# Magento 2 Installation Error on 2.3.5

Tags: magento2

HI am trying to install magento 2.3.5 on my linux mint cinammon 19.3 however the instalaltion is succesful but am not able to acess the admin area as well and my frontend css looks totally destroyed
please take a look at the screenshot below

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any help on this this is ,y first time with magento on linux so am facing difficulties thankss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is actually in Url Rewrite

1st Try the First Check that rewrites module is enabled or not in your apache server if not then enable and restart the server

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 restart
```

if You are Still Facing this Problem

go to `etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Change

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
to

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then

```
service apache2 restart
```

`

if this doesn't work then most probably

Please Deploy Static Content with language Code Propel Something like that

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_GB // UK English
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US // US English
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f pt_PT // Portoguese
```

Comment: yes am exactly trying the same thing

Comment: do you have tried all steps one by one?